# ng2 inherit from component and extend parent template

Tags: angular, angular2-template

i have a component inherits from base component.

i want to extend the template of base component in derived component.

ex.
template in base component:

```
<div>
   <button>1</button>
</div>
```

template in derived component:

```
<div>
   <button>2</button>
</div>
```

and i want to see button 1 and button 2

Is there any way to do it?
Thanks!

Comment: you can do it, lot of stuff available out there,do bit research.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the html depending from where is your button 2 just use the selector from the template 2 as following :

ts button2:

```
 @Component({
   selector: 'app-mybutton2',
```

html button1:

```
<div>
   <button>1</button>
</div>
<app-mybutton2></app-mybutton2>
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot extend html files. However, if i understand you well you need to create custom component and use it inside your component.

For the typescript files you can make the component extend any typescript class and two typescript files can share the same template html file.